# Which Role in SSRS is suitable in the below context

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

An  ssrs installation is in a native mode. An item role named Developer is 
Present on the  server.The Developer role cannot view and modify report caching parameters.
But,there is a need to  ensure the Developer role can **view and modify caching parameters**. Which task need to be  add to developer role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to Security Roles for managing access and permissions to various parts of the server. The default set of Roles does not include Developer (as far as I know, see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156014%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for the extent of my knowledge and experience), however, I know custom roles can be created somehow.

Per this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee636367.aspx), you would need to assign an additional role of Content Manager or Publisher to the user(s) in question. [My Reports](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255206.aspx) works too but that's only good if the shared data sources whose cached parameters need to be managed are being accessed solely from within a specified developer's directory.

Comment: Manage report history is the task i was searching for